# How to convert a string to a JSON and then extract required values from the JSON object?

Tags: java, json, gson, freebase

I have a string as below, I want to convert it to a JSON object and then extract all the values of "text" field:

```
{
 "id": "/m/030qb3t",
  "property": {
   "/travel/travel_destination/tourist_attractions": {
    "valuetype": "object",
    "values": [
    {
     "text": "Hollywood Wax Museum",
     "lang": "en",
     "id": "/m/07_dsf",
     "creator": "/user/rumifield",
     "timestamp": "2008-12-27T17:02:32.000Z"
    },
    {
     "text": "Hollywood Walk of Fame",
     "lang": "en",
     "id": "/m/0qjfl",
     "creator": "/user/rumifield",
     "timestamp": "2008-12-27T17:02:32.000Z"
    },
    {
     "text": "TCL Chinese Theatre",
     "lang": "en",
     "id": "/m/04n2h_",
     "creator": "/user/rumifield",
     "timestamp": "2008-12-27T17:02:32.000Z"
    },
    {
     "text": "Museum of Tolerance",
     "lang": "en",
     "id": "/m/04by8k",
     "creator": "/user/rumifield",
     "timestamp": "2008-12-27T17:02:32.001Z"
    },
    {
     "text": "Getty Center",
     "lang": "en",
     "id": "/m/01mvl6",
     "creator": "/user/rumifield",
     "timestamp": "2008-12-27T17:02:32.001Z"
    },
    {
     "text": "Museum of Contemporary Art, Los Angeles",
     "lang": "en",
     "id": "/m/02816j",
     "creator": "/user/rumifield",
     "timestamp": "2008-12-27T17:02:32.001Z"
    },
    {
     "text": "Griffith Park",
     "lang": "en",
     "id": "/m/02sdph",
     "creator": "/user/rumifield",
     "timestamp": "2008-12-27T17:02:32.001Z"
    },
    {
     "text": "Hollywood Boulevard",
     "lang": "en",
     "id": "/m/035zpq",
     "creator": "/user/rumifield",
     "timestamp": "2008-12-27T17:02:32.002Z"
    },
    {
     "text": "Olvera Street",
     "lang": "en",
     "id": "/m/030svs",
     "creator": "/user/rumifield",
     "timestamp": "2008-12-27T17:02:32.002Z"
    },
    {
     "text": "Centinela Adobe",
     "lang": "en",
     "id": "/m/04drm4",
     "creator": "/user/supergmackenz",
     "timestamp": "2011-12-13T18:45:26.003Z"
    }
   ],
   "count": 27.0
  }
 }
}
```

I've tried

```
JsonParser jsParser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsObject = (JsonObject)jsParser.parse(jsonStr);
String text=jsObject.getString("text");
```

but it doesn't work and I don't know how to extract all the "text" values, any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at first you need to understand in JSON you need to access the value from top to bottom, not directly to the key. I guess this will do what you want
This is for 2.3 gson library

```
JsonParser jsParser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsObject = (JsonObject)jsParser.parse(jsonStr);
JsonObject property = jsObject.getAsJsonObject("property");
JsonObject tourist  = property.getAsJsonObject("/travel/travel_destination/tourist_attractions");
JsonArray  values   = tourist.getAsJsonArray("values"); 
for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++) {
    JsonObject data = values.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
    String text = data.get("text").getAsString();
}
```

I hope my answer is clear enough. If you have any question regarding my answer feel free to ask in the comment :)

Comment: thank you, but don't know why, the program throws "java.lang.NullPointerException" in line of for loop...

Answer (score 1):

In this json `values` is an array, so try

```
JSONObject getObject = object.getJSONObject("property");
JSONObject block  =  getObject.getJSONObject("/travel/travel_destination/tourist_attractions");
JSONArray getArray = block.getJSONArray("values");

for(int i = 0; i < getArray.size(); i++)
{
    JSONObject jsObject= getArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String text=jsObject.getString("text");
}
```

Comment: What jar should I use?

Comment: personally I use `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
 <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Time to upgrade!

Comment: I have used org.json.jar, tried your code like below, but it throws error of "org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["values"] not found.    "JSONObject js=new JSONObject(inputLine);
        JSONObject getObject = js.getJSONObject("property");
        JSONArray getArray = getObject.getJSONArray("values");
      for(int i = 0; i < getArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject jO= getArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String text=jO.getString("text");
            System.out.println(text);
        }

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This is the latest version of this jar - what do you recommend?

Comment: Jackson upgraded (breaking all backwards compatibility) to version 2. See [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.4.2).